# JSDoc - How to show parameter type as the same type of the base class method?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

```
class BaseFooBar {
    /** @param {number} bar */
    foo(bar) {
        console.log('bar is' + bar);
    }
}

class FooBar extends BaseFooBar {
    foo(bar) {
        // Any way to show [bar] type as "number" instead of "any"

        console.log('bar is' + bar);
    }
}
```

In the `FooBar` class, the parameter `bar` from the `foo()` method show as type `any`. There's any way to show `bar` as type `number` without having to specify again using `/** @param {number} bar */`?

Comment: Does the `@extends` class-level doc not make that happen automagically? https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-classes.html

Comment: @DaveNewton Unfortunately not, I just tried it now.